Postgresql 15 и TimescaleDB падают запросы
Используется Postres 15 и TimesacaleDB.
При попытке что то удалить из таблицы Timescale, база улетает в recovery.
Пример:
DELETE FROM visits_hits WHERE date between '2023-06-01' AND '2023-06-02';

При попытке декомпресии чанков, база улетает в recovery.
Пример:
SELECT decompress_chunk(c, true) FROM show_chunks('visits_hits', '2023-09-06'::date, '2023-05-26'::date) c;

Есть ли идеи как это можно пофиксить?
Выдержка из логов постгреса:

2024-04-04 11:47:16.239 MSK (00000) [2612269] LOG:  server process (PID 3332982) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2024-04-04 11:47:16.239 MSK (00000) [2612269] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT decompress_chunk(c, true) FROM show_c
hunks('visits_hits', '2023-09-06'::date, '2023-05-26'::date) c
2024-04-04 11:47:16.239 MSK (00000) [2612269] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2024-04-04 11:47:16.242 MSK (00000) [2612269] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2024-04-04 11:47:16.464 MSK (00000) [3333015] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-04-04 11:44:32 MSK
2024-04-04 11:47:16.609 MSK (00000) [3333015] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2024-04-04 11:47:16.613 MSK (00000) [3333015] LOG:  redo starts at 120A/2DC7E9F8
2024-04-04 11:47:19.185 MSK (00000) [3333015] LOG:  invalid record length at 120A/613F1390: wanted 24, got 0
2024-04-04 11:47:19.185 MSK (00000) [3333015] LOG:  redo done at 120A/613F1358 system usage: CPU: user: 1.90 s, system: 0.66 s, elapsed: 2.57 s
2024-04-04 11:47:19.193 MSK (00000) [3333016] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait
2024-04-04 11:47:20.140 MSK (00000) [3333016] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 101958 buffers (11.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 52 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.770 s, sync=0.003 s, total=0.948 s; sync files=221, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=843210 kB, estimate=843210 kB
2024-04-04 11:47:20.176 MSK (00000) [2612269] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2024-04-04 11:47:20.177 MSK (00000) [3333065] LOG:  TimescaleDB background worker launcher connected to shared catalogs


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

Проверить версии установленной СУБД и TimescaleDB расширения. Поставить минорные обновления если доступны.
Если Segmentation fault будет продолжать происходить на актуальных версиях - то поставить dbgsym пакеты базы и TimescaleDB, gdb, включить снятие core dumps в вашей операционной системе (зависит от ОС, конечно, в linux смотрите по направлению /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern, нужно что-то вроде core.%e.%p.SIG%s.%t)
Затем через gdb открыть сформированный при Segmentation fault core dump, выполнить команду backtrace и с полученным листингом пойти открывать багрепорт к postgresql или TimescaleDB. Скорей всего сперва именно к разработчикам TimescaleDB.

больше всего похоже на https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/6028. в issues много похожего https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues?q=is%3Aissue+LOG%3A+database+system+was+not+properly+shut+down%3B+automatic+recovery+in+progress

поэтому первое - это проверить, не было ли исправлено давно уже. А вот искать похожие segfault без backtrace штука неблагодарная. Если это ошибка в коде - то она может быть много где и разной в каждом из issue, если же это не ошибка кода, а неожиданное повреждение данных - то его без глубокого залезания внутрь тем более искать трудно.
